# How to create a DBConnectivity utility class in python automation which returns/creates single dbconnection for whole test suite

Tags: python, database, automation

I am doing automation is Python first time, as per requirement am trying to create a Database utility class which create the dbconnection and contains different functions for db related operations.
My objective is to create a single DB Connection for the complete test suite instead of creating dbconnection for each function call.

Which could be extended to other utility class as well like browser and others

Answer (score 0):

The times that I had to

> create the dbconnection

I've used [Object pool](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/object-pool-design-pattern/). It allows you to manage initializing a class instance that is very expensive. Also, if you plan to reuse and share with other modules, it will support your parallel test execution.

In case you need just sequential mode in test execution, depending from your Testing framework, you can place the DBConnection initialization in the `before` hook and inject it in each test.

Sample python code:

```
class ReusablePool:
    """
    Manage Reusable objects for use by Client objects.
    """

    def __init__(self, size):
        self._reusables = [Reusable() for _ in range(size)]

    def acquire(self):
        return self._reusables.pop()

    def release(self, reusable):
        self._reusables.append(reusable)


class Reusable:
"""
Collaborate with other objects for a limited amount of time, then
they are no longer needed for that collaboration.
"""

    pass


def main():
    reusable_pool = ReusablePool(10)
    reusable = reusable_pool.acquire()
    reusable_pool.release(reusable)


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```